# how to bind two dimensional array with excel range in vsto

Tags: c#, vsto

I want to get Excel cell values as a 2D array without using a for loop in a VSTO add-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Excel.Range rng = myWorksheet.get_Range("A1:D4", Type.Missing);

//Get a 2D Array of values from the range in one shot:
object[,] myArray = (object[,])rng.get_Value(Type.Missing);
```